# How to add new registery keys on installation of a win form applicaiton to create a custom uri scheme?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, winforms

I had created a winform application and want to create a custom URI scheme for it. I was able to create it by creating registry keys for that URI scheme in my system. But I want to create those registry keys on the installation of the app so that it can be used on any system?

Comment: Do you use an installer? If so that's the place to do it, if not you could check for the scheme existence when your app starts & if its not found create it.

Comment: Can I get the sample code somewhere to create that?

Answer (score 0):

When creating your installation's msi or exe or whatever, there must be a way to prealably set registry keys depending on the software you're using.

You can also do it through code at the beginning of your program but that would be a waste. Look at the [RegistryKey class](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

EDIT :

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("MyNewSubKey");

        using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey subsubkey = regKey.CreateSubKey("MyNewSubSubKey"))
        {
            subsubkey.SetValue("The cake", "U got the cake !");

            Console.WriteLine((String)(subsubkey.GetValue("The cake", "The cake is a lie"))); //Print U got the cake if success. Otherwise print "The cake is a lie"
        }
```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015. can you please tell me what could be the possible way to set these keys?

Comment: That's a whole story, but I like the old Installer Project Template for that kind of stuff. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects

Comment: There's surely a way using app.config too. But better use an already existing feature in a packaging & deployment software

Comment: Okay, I have set the registry key via installer. But it only works in the local system. When I build and install the .exe file in my local system it creates the registry settings. But when I publish the application and download from the link. It does not create them at all.